# How do the Xindi fit in with the humanoid origin theory presented in “The Chase”?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, star-trek-enterprise, star-trek-eu

In *The Next Generation* episode “The Chase” it states that all humanoids come from the same ancestral species however the Xindi (which have six species) only some of them are humanoid. How does this work? Also which Xindi species are humanoids and which are not?

Comment: Not all humanoids in the Galaxy came from the aliens in The Chase.

Comment: i was under the impression they were can you verify that?

Comment: I'm honestly at a loss what would constitute a good answer in your opinion. Can you be more specific? Are you just looking for us to confirm a fan-theory of yours?

Comment: I'm just trying to find a way to understand something that doesn't make sense to me

Answer (score 10):

The "seed code" seems to push individual species toward a humanoid shape and size. This doesn't, however, preclude other forms being chosen by evolutionary pressure and natural selection. On Earth, for example, we see the earliest space-faring species arising [from dinosaurs](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Voth). Over time they *became* humanoid but they certainly didn't start that way. Perhaps, over time, the non-humanoid Xindi species will eventually become progressively more humanoid.

> **HUMANOID:** (continuing)
>               *Our scientists seeded the
>               primordial oceans of many worlds,
>               where life was in its infancy.
>               **These seed codes directed your
>               evolution toward a physical form
>               resembling ours** -- this body you
>               see before you.*
>
> <sub><sup>TNG: The Chase</sup></sub>

That being said, we know that the seeding happened on a few planets (at least 19) but it's a very big galaxy and life has almost certainly arisen ***independently*** on thousands or millions of other planets unconnected to the progenitors.

Comment: I believe this an unacceptable answer since it is extremely unlikely that humanoid life just happened to evolve on multiple worlds,

Comment: @BenjaminErickson - The makers of Mudd's Androids came from another galaxy. They were (as far as we can tell) humanoid

Comment: @BenjaminErickson - The Sphere Builders were humanoid but came from another dimension; https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Sphere-Builder

Comment: @BenjaminErickson - The aliens in TNG: Schisms are from a different subspace domain but are clearly humanoid(ish)

Comment: It is never stated that the seeders seeded only milky way planets

Comment: @BenjaminErickson - Sure. If you discount every extra-galactic civilisation as being *probably seeded by the seeders* then it's impossible to prove a negative

Comment: I'm only saying all HUMANOIDS are seeded but, you are right, there are inexplicable anomalies in the star trek universe.

Comment: That makes sense however you must also realize that in is extremely unlikely that sentient species that all look them same (somewhat), have the same body features  and aren't related in any way to each other, it is even more unlikely that on one planet (Xindus) more than one sentient non-humanoid and more than one sentient humanoid just happened to evolve.

Comment: @BenjaminErickson The presence of all these humanoids in the galaxy, besides the ones seeded by the Progenitors, could be a case of convergent evolution, ie under similar external pressures life will evolve towards similar solutions.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105518/discussion-on-answer-by-valorum-how-do-the-xindi-fit-in-with-the-humanoid-origin).

Comment: “it is extremely unlikely that humanoid life just happened to evolve on multiple worlds” — it's also extremely unlikely that the Roman Empire evolved on another planet besides earth, but [that happened, apparently](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Bread_and_Circuses_(episode)).

Comment: Everyone remembers "The Chase" when looking for the answer to the prevalence of humanoid body structures in Trek, but no one ever remembers "Return to Tomorrow"......

Answer (score 2):

## They likely don't relate at all.

In *The Chase*, an ancient species seeded the galaxy something like 4 billion years ago. However, out of the thousands of worlds and lifeforms in the Enterprise's databanks, if not millions, only lifeforms from 19 known worlds contained their "algorithm".

> COMPUTER: Pattern match found.
>
> CRUSHER: Specify.
>
> COMPUTER: The number blocks are mathematical representations of fragments of deoxyribonucleic acid strands.
>
> PICARD: DNA fragments?
>
> CRUSHER: Each from a different lifeform from nineteen different worlds.
>
> PICARD: The planets that these fragments are from are scattered across the quadrant. No wonder it took the Professor so long to collect them.

...

> PICARD: So, four billion years ago someone scattered this genetic material into the primordial soup of at least nineteen different planets across the galaxy?

*The Chase* establishes that the vast majority of known worlds and lifeforms were *not* seeded by this race, not *all humanoid life*. So the odds that the Xindi homeworld was seeded by this race is extremely low. Furthermore, this race lived and died sometime around 4 billion years ago, long before many contemporary worlds, including possibly Xindus, had the opportunity to form. The most likely answer is that they are unrelated.